# gcloud alpha resource-manager folders get-iam-policy is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/resource-manager/folders/get-iam-policy#FOLDER

THis seems to be broken. its not saying the folder doesn't exists its saying the arg is invalid. this is the example from the doc

```
❯ gcloud alpha resource-manager folders get-iam-policy my-folder                                                                    
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.resource-manager.folders.get-iam-policy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Comment: did you try the end of doc, in NOTES? likes: gcloud resource-manager ... or : gcloud beta resource-manager ...

Comment: What is "my-folder"? Folder Name or Folder ID? It should be a Folder ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in reference-alpha, the argument seems to be changed from

> FOLDER

to

> FOLDER_ID

likes [reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/resource-manager/folders/get-iam-policy) and [reference-beta](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/resource-manager/folders/get-iam-policy).

only reference-alpha's document was not revised

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager folders get-iam-policy 3589215982
```

above works with no INVALID_ARGUMENT error